# Is it possible to push .json file from BigQuery to Firebase using Python?

Tags: python, firebase

I fetched the data (.csv) from BigQuery. I have done some data cleaning using Python and created a new table in BigQuery. Now, I like to get .json file for that table and push it to firebase using Python.

I am quite new to Firebase and stuck here. Could anyone please help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can :) by using the python package 'firebase'

### Installation

```
pip install firebase
```

#### Python Version

Firebase was written for python 3 and above and will not work correctly with python 2.

#### Add Firebase to your Application

Your Google's Firebase configuration data can be found on [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com) > Settings > Project Settings *Scroll to bottom* > Add to web app > config

For use with only user based authentication we can create the following configuration:

```py
from firebase import Firebase

config = {
  "apiKey": "apiKey",
  "authDomain": "projectId.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://databaseName.firebaseio.com",
  "storageBucket": "projectId.appspot.com"
}

firebase = Firebase(config)
```

### Database

You can build paths to your data by using the `child()` method.

```py
db = firebase.database()
db.child("BigQuery").child("Ojbect_1")
```

#### Save Data

push

To save data with a unique, auto-generated, timestamp-based key, use the `push()` method.

```py
data = {"Object_1": <Your JSON Data>}
db.child("BigQuery").push(data)
```

set

To create your own keys use the `set()` method. The key in the example below is "Object_2".

```py
data = {"data": <More JSON Data>}
db.child("BigQuery").child("Object_2").set(data)
```

update

To update data for an existing entry use the `update()` method.

```py
db.child("BigQuery").child("Object_2").update({"data": <Updated More JSON Data>})
```

remove

To delete data for an existing entry use the `remove()` method.

```py
db.child("BigQuery").child("Object_2").remove()
```

I hope this helps :) More information / full docs: https://pypi.org/project/firebase

Comment: Thanks, Joe for your detail answer. It helps me :)

Comment: You're welcome :) if it helped you make sure to up-vote and flag to help others in the future.